# Pointwise estimate for a sequence of mollified functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In the answer to [Characterisation of one-dimensional Sobolev space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903881/characterisation-of-one-dimensional-sobolev-space) Tomás wrote

> ... let $\eta_\delta$ be the [standard mollifier sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Concrete_example). Let $u_\delta=\eta_\delta\star u$ and note that for any $c\in (a,b)$ $$|u_\delta(x)-u_\epsilon(x)|\le \int_c^x |u'_\delta (t)-u'_\epsilon(t)|dt+|u_\delta (c)-u_\epsilon(c)|\tag{1}.$$

Since I am new to this subject, I'd like to know which theorem/lemma Tomás used to get inequality (1).

Comment: Post it as a comment under his answer.

Comment: I am unable to, my reputation points have to be over 50 to comment under the answer.

Comment: OK, 6 more up-votes and you're there. Here's one from me...

Comment: @barakmanos Spurious upvotes are to be avoided. This issue was discussed, and resolved, on [Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16673/147263).

Comment: @Thursday: OK, sorry, I cannot revert that by now (BTW, it looks as though I wasn't the only one)...

Comment: @barakmanos Actually, now you can (not that you have to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that $$u_\delta(x)=u_\delta (c)+\int_c^xu_\delta'(t)dt,$$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: Indeed I can. Thank you very much for your clarification. Sorry for causing such a fuss due to my lack of reputation points.